# What are some different ways of making an effective email validation method without using regular expression in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I was requested to do email validation that will check the following conditions without regex(I was asked by the teacher to do it like that):

1. Check that @ exist once in the string
2. Check that left sub string (left to @) isn't empty
3. Check that right sub string (right to @) isn't empty
4. Check that . exist in right sub string (right to @)
5. Check that left sub sub string isn't empty (right to @, left to .)
6. Check that right sub sub string's length is at least 2

Here was one of my attempts, wasn't able to make it work...

```
- (BOOL) checkIfValidEmail{
    BOOL helper = NO;
    if ([self length] < 6) {
        return NO;
    }else
    {
        NSMutableArray *charArray = [NSMutableArray new];
        for (int i = 0; i < [self length]; i++) {
            NSString *charte = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", [self characterAtIndex:i]];
            [charArray addObject:charte];
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < [self length]; i++) {
            NSString *charter = charArray[i];
            if ([@"@"isEqualToString:charter] && helper == NO ) {
                helper = YES;
            }

            if ([@"." isEqualToString:charter] && helper == YES) {
                helper = YES;
            }

        }

    }
    return helper;
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you don't want regex?

Comment: You've got the makings of an algorithm, there. Have you tried implementing it and seeing what happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my attempt

```
@interface Tester : NSObject
+(BOOL) testForValidMail:(NSString *)mail;
@end

@implementation Tester

+(BOOL)testForValidMail:(NSString *)string
{

    NSRange atRange = [string rangeOfString:@"@"];

    BOOL b = NO;

    if ((atRange.location != NSNotFound) //is `@` present
        && (atRange.location != 0) // and is `@` not at the beginning -> left substring exist
        && (atRange.location != string.length-1) // and not at the end -> right substring exists
        && ([[string componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"] count] == 2)) // and is there only one `@`?
    {
        // is there a `.` right of the `@`?
        NSRange dotRange = [[string substringFromIndex:atRange.length +atRange.location] rangeOfString:@"."];

        if((dotRange.location != NSNotFound) // is there a `.` right of `@`
           && (dotRange.location !=0) // and is it not the very next char after `@`
           && ([[string substringFromIndex:[string length]-2] rangeOfString:@"."].location == NSNotFound)) // and the `.` is not the last or second last char
        {
            b = YES;
        }
    }
    return b;
}

@end


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
    NSArray *candidates = @[@"m@m.de",
                            @"m@.de",
                            @"m@m.e",
                            @"@m.de",
                            @"m<at>m.de",
                            @"mm@mm@mm.de",
                            @"email@email.email.email.com" //if you are the owner of email.com, you can decide to create this address
                            ];
    [candidates enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *mailAdress, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            NSLog(@"%@, %@",([Tester testForValidMail:mailAdress]) ? @"YES" : @"NO", mailAdress );
        }];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

result:

```
2014-02-14 21:05:49.404 emailcheck[16271:303] YES, m@m.de
2014-02-14 21:05:49.405 emailcheck[16271:303] NO, m@.de
2014-02-14 21:05:49.406 emailcheck[16271:303] NO, m@m.e
2014-02-14 21:05:49.406 emailcheck[16271:303] NO, @m.de
2014-02-14 21:05:49.406 emailcheck[16271:303] NO, m<at>m.de
2014-02-14 21:05:49.407 emailcheck[16271:303] NO, mm@mm@mm.de
2014-02-14 21:05:49.407 emailcheck[16271:303] YES, email@email.email.email.com
```

---

I added another check: not more than one `@`

---

I rewrote my code as Category on NSString

```
@interface NSString (EmailAddressTest)
-(BOOL) isValidMailAddress;
@end

@implementation NSString (EmailAddressTest)

-(BOOL)isValidMailAddress
{
     NSRange atRange = [self rangeOfString:@"@"];

    BOOL b = NO;

    if ((atRange.location != NSNotFound) //is `@` present
        && (atRange.location != 0) // and is `@` not at the beginning -> left substring exist
        && (atRange.location != [self length]-1) // and not at the end -> right substring exists
        && ([[self componentsSeparatedByString:@"@"] count] == 2)) // and is there only one `@`?
    {
        // is there a `.` right of the `@`?
        NSRange dotRange = [[self substringFromIndex:atRange.length +atRange.location] rangeOfString:@"."];

        if((dotRange.location != NSNotFound) // is there a `.` right of `@`
           && (dotRange.location !=0) // and is it not the very next char after `@`
           && ([[self substringFromIndex:[self length]-2] rangeOfString:@"."].location == NSNotFound)) // and the `.` is not the last or second last char
        {
            b = YES;
        }
    }
    return b;
}

@end


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    @autoreleasepool {
        [@[@"m@m.de", @"m@.de", @"m@m.e", @"@m.de", @"m<at>m.de", @"mm@mm@mm.de"] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *mailAdress, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
            NSLog(@"%@, %@",([mailAdress isValidMailAddress]) ? @"YES" : @"NO", mailAdress );
        }];
    }
    return 0;
}
```